# UITableViewCell - displaying accessory view beside rearrange control

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, ipad

In the Safari bookmarks manager on iPhone, the `UITableView` seems to have behaviour that isn't standard. I'm referring to this:

[alt text http://cl.ly/b7f0faead6a8586d3470/content](http://cl.ly/b7f0faead6a8586d3470/content)

In edit mode, the bookmark UITableViewCells have both a rearrange control and a `UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator` accessory view next to them. How do you get both? In my table views, when you go into edit mode to reveal the rearrange control, the control takes the place of the accessory view, it doesn't display both.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use editingAccessoryType property of UITableViewCell.

Comment: That answers one of my questions, but I still need to know how to display both the accessory view and the rearrange control

Comment: Rearrange controls are your table view controller's responsibility, specifically its data source and delegate methods. If the data source supports rearranging a given range of cells, they will show the controls while in editing mode.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, editingAccessoryType does display the accessory view next to the rearrange control. Thanks!